# PostGIS compute orthogonal points at a given distance

Tags: postgis

In PostGIS, I need to compute the 2 perpendicular points C and D at a given distance of a line so that it creates a perfect rectangle on the map. The projection WGS84. ABCD has to be anticlockwise like in the drawing below.

Any idea how to compte those 2 points?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an arbitrary linestring, you can use [ST_OffsetCurve](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OffsetCurve.html) to compute a parallel line with a custom distance (set to 2 meters in this example). We reverse it afterwards. Then you can connect the start and endpoints of the 2 linestrings with each other which will yield the "connecting" linestrings.

[image]

```
WITH focus_line AS (
    SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LineString(-0.108092 51.519324, -0.107643 51.517861)', 4326) AS geom
), 
parallel_line AS (
    SELECT ST_Reverse(
        ST_Transform(
            ST_OffsetCurve(
                ST_Transform(
                    geom, 
                3857),
            2, 'join=round'),
        4326)
    ) AS geom
    FROM focus_line
)
SELECT ST_AsText(a.geom) AS focus,
ST_AsText(b.geom) AS parallel,
ST_AsText(
    ST_MakeLine(
        ST_StartPoint(a.geom), ST_EndPoint(b.geom)
    )
) AS connection_1, 
ST_AsText(
    ST_MakeLine(
        ST_EndPoint(a.geom), ST_StartPoint(b.geom)  
    )
) AS connection_2
FROM focus_line a, parallel_line b;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. Working perfect! Thanks